# Passing cell value of unknown type into overloaded method in DataTable loop

Tags: c#, types, datatable, npoi

First time working with strict type language and having some problems.

Data fetched from MySQL adapter fills a DataTable object.
Column types remains the same as in MySQL table.

Initiating NPOI, creating xls sheet. Next step is writing data in loop. And here is the problem.

http://pastebin.com/NzVqzWE0

Method SetCellValue has overloadings for all needed types, but can it guess for more appropriate overloading automaticly? Am i missing something?

Converting all values to strings cant help because i need number formating in sheet.
Technically this code works, im looking for right way of handling this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can defer the overload resolution to the runtime by using the `dynamic` keyword:

```
foreach (DataColumn column in data.Columns)
{
    ICell cell = dataRow.CreateCell(column.Ordinal);
    cell.SetCellValue((dynamic)row[column]);
}
```

Please note that this will fail with a runtime exception if there is no matching overload.

Comment: Works great. Thanks. Just added check for value != System.DBNull.